# centrar contenedor de modulos

Tags: bootstrap, reactjs

Estoy intentando realizar un centrado horizontal y vertical de un div con bootstrap pero no logro dar con la clase adecuada. Este div contiene 3 componentes que renderizan un botón cada uno.

```
function Login() {
 return (
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-sm-5">
      <div className="p-3">
        <LoginGoogle />
      </div>
      <div className="p-3">
        <LoginSaml />
      </div>
      <div className="p-3">
        <LoginAuth0 />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

);
}

export default Login;

Quitando el contenedor principal no hay ningún cambio, no tengo experiencia con estilos, y quería saber si se puede lograr esto con bootstrap gracias!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [`align-items-center`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#alignment)

Comment: podrías ser mas específico?

Comment: ¿Más especifico que el nombre de la clase que buscas con enlace a la documentación de lo que quieres lograr con ejemplos visuales y de código? si, me cuesta bastante ser mas específico.

Comment: Perdón Nicolás, no me había percatado de que era un enlace